Raspberry Pi Pico only works when plugged into PC usb
I made a basic program that turns my pc on and off at certain times of the day and it works as long as it's plugged into a usb port on the pc. I want the script to work on the PI so I can integrate it into the hardware independent of Thonny. But after saving the script as main.py on the Pico, when I unplug it and plug it back into power through a usb wall adapter all that works is the blinking 'led'. Why is that? Is there a special process I need to follow when changing power sources?
Here is my code;
from machine import Pin
import time

led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)
picoPin = Pin(15, Pin.OUT) #create picoPin at Pin 15, Set to output
pcOn = Pin(16, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

def SwitchOn():
    if not pcOn.value():   #If PC is off
        picoPin.value(0)    #Set picoPin turn off
        time.sleep(1.0) #Maintain for 1s then continue
        
    else:
        print("PC ALREADY ON")
        

def SwitchOff():
    if pcOn.value():    #If PC is on
        picoPin.value(0)    #Set picoPin turn off
        time.sleep(1.0) #Maintain for 5s then continue
        
    else:
        print("PC ALREADY OFF")
        

try:
    while True:
        led.value(1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        picoPin.value(1)    # Keep picoPin turn on
        now = time.localtime()
        timeNow = "{}:{}:{}".format(now[3], now[4], now[5])
        print(timeNow)
        if timeNow == "14:43:0":
            SwitchOff()
           
        if timeNow == "14:45:0":
            SwitchOn()
            
        led.value(0)
        time.sleep(0.5)

except:
    pass


When your Pico is not plugged into your PC how is it going to get the time?

I’m voting to close this question because this is not actually a question at all... I'm guessing that the OP might be struggling with something else.

This question is lacking any detail about how the Pico is connected. As others have pointed out without an internet connection or RTC the Pico (which) won't know the time.

You don't have to use Thonny. I run programs on my Pico without Thonny.

Milliways and @CoderMike I didn’t think it would need external input for the time. I thought it’s all integrated into the language due to the Epoch counter that maintains independently of any validating network or similar. Let me try it from my Pico W connected to the internet and see if it works.

The Pico RTC defaults to 1/1/2021 0:0:0 on powerup. Thonny sets time. You would need to sync with NTP - maybe works with mpremote but I never tried.

Yup that right there is my issue. If you type up a formal response I will mark it as the answer! I was not aware of this caveat in hardware development. I will have to set the RTC somehow at the start of my program.

When you disconnect the Pico you remove power so the program stops.
You either have to continuously supply power from some other source or arrange for the program to start running when power is applied.
This can be accomplished by saving the program as main.py.

The Pico RTC defaults to 1/1/2021 0:0:0 on powerup. Thonny sets time.

The following will set & display time on a PicoW
import time
import ntptime
ntptime.settime()
print(time.localtime())


This prints:-
(2024, 4, 9, 6, 52, 29, 1, 100)
You will need to download the ntptime module to the PicoW.

NOTE this appears to be gmtime; if you want localtime you will need to specify timezone. This is a large file (too big for Pico). Thonny appears to do the conversion before uploading time.

what about the fact that if he's not plugged into his PC he can't know whether it's ON or OFF?

Most microcontrollers run a program in firmware which starts automatically when powered. The Pico is somewhat different, because the program it runs is the interpreter so you need to ensure that python runs the program. The Pico runs when power is applied (unless forced into RESET).

Yeah - I know that - but if he's controlling a PC from a Pico would there not have to be an OTG connection for that to work?

@Seamus I think the idea is bizarre, but the program seems to be using a GPIO pin to control the PC, if that is connected it should work. Frankly if they are connected I fail to see why you wouldn't also use USB to power it, but that wasn't the question.

OK - just wanted to make sure I hadn't missed something obvious :)

I saved the program as main.py and as I stated at least part of the program is running because the light blinks as it should but the GPIO pins are not flipping on and off at the assigned interval. The PI is being powered through a USB to Micro USB cable but I don’t want it to be powered from an external port on the PC. My goal is to get a molex to micro USB cable so it can be powered from inside but I’ll do that after I get it to work properly.
